# How do I open the locked door at the the bottom of the abandoned tower?

Tags: silversword

In [Silversword](http://silversword-rpg.com/), there is a watchtower just outside of the starting town, which is pretty much the 2nd dungeon you'll go to in the game. The name for it that it shows on the screen when you enter is *Abandoned Tower*. When you go downstairs, there is a locked gate. This is *not* the gate I'm having a problem with, since the key to that is at the top of the tower.

But on the same level of the tower, beyond that locked gate, there is a wall you can walk through that leads to a secret area, and in that area there is a door you can walk to. A message appears which says "The door to the south appears to be locked". Unlike all the other locked doors up to this point in the game, no user-interface options pop up for me to try to force the door, pick the lock, or use an item on it.

[image: this isn't a screenshot I took with my cellphone, I swear]

I ended up just leaving it alone and moving on to the next dungeon. So far I've seen nothing that indicates I should return and try again. Is there any way to get through that locked door?

Answer (score 1):

The locked door is open once you get the Dragon Egg (hidden in the dragon tower).

Answer (score -1):

It can be opened in the full version game. Looks like it will remain mysterious for now.

Comment: I have the full version of the game.